# Tetromino(kind of tetris) strategy, probabilty to complete an area

Tags: math, geometry, probability, tetris, probability-theory

**Hi everyone.There is a kind of tetris game. I need to fill this area with the pieces below.(the pieces has no rotation and reflection)**

[image: the area]

[image: blue piece]
[image: red piece]
[image: square piece]
[image: green piece]
[image: yellow piece]
[image: orange piece]

**When the game starts, you will have a random piece which you may use that piece or you can throw it. After that, you will get anothor piece randomly(all six pieces have the same probabilty) and so on.
The point is to complete the whole area by using maximum 10 pieces.(you use the piece or throw it both count).The question is how to play this game perfectly.I mean, How can I decide a piece to throw or keep and where to place it.Every move will change the probabilty of completing the puzzle up to 10 move and, I need to keep that probabilty higher.What would the best strategy be? Thanks for help.**

Comment: If the pieces are random there is no possibility of predicting perfect game apart from luck.

Comment: The best you can do is show next tetromino and use form of heuristic (if can form a hole that fits for the next shape) just like in tetris... other option is count the probability of each shape occuring and handle it as next shape if probability is high ...